# Error while running SSIS package as a job

Tags: excel, ssis

I am trying to create a job for SSIS packages that is used to process excel files and upload them into database. I have a script task in the package that uses excel dll - `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to format the excel files that I get.

The packages run fine when i run it locally(run with Visual Studio) in the server so I can assume all the assembles are installed correctly. But when i create a job to run the package i get the following error

> " Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version
>   13.0.1100.288 for 32-bit  Copyright (c) 2015 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  5:14:35 PM  Error: 2016-05-23 17:14:37.31
>   Code: 0x00000001     Source: Script Task      Description: Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  End Error  DTExec:
>   The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  5:14:35
>   PM  Finished: 5:14:37 PM  Elapsed:  2.312 seconds.  The package
>   execution failed.  The step failed."

I have set the jobstep to use `32-bit` runtime. 
[image]

I have also set Run64bitRuntime as false in the project configuration properties.
[image]

It doesn't give any more information on the error.

I have logging enabled and it is working since I checked it running locally.

I have added a log message at the main function of script task to know if the main function is getting executed.

But The log files show the target of invocation error before the main function log message.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: When you say you run it locally in the server, do you mean that you run it using visual studio on the server?  Also when you set 32-bit runtime, you are setting it in the configuration in SSISDB or just in the project properties in visual studio?

Comment: Yes, I am running it using Visual Studio on the server. I have set the Run64bitRuntime as false in the project configuration properties.

Comment: Basic question: do you have Excel installed on your server?

Comment: You might put try/catch blocks in your script to raise a more meaningful error message depending on which line of code raises the error.   With "target of invocation" it really helps to know which line of code it's on.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Excel is installed in the server.

Comment: @TabAlleman I do have try catch blocks in the script.

Comment: Ok, but what about the rest of my comment?   Just having them isn't doing you much good apparently, if you don't know what line of code is causing the error.

Comment: I have places log messages in the first lines of code in main method with try catch block, but it doesn't get logged. I will post my code in sometime